# How to calculate grams of fat used during hibernation?

Tags: metabolism, energy, fat-metabolism, energy-metabolism, bats

In [Humphries et al. 2002. Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature00828), the authors report number of grams of fat bats use during hibernation. However, their equations results in values in mlO2/g.

How can one convert the energy requirements to amount of burnt fat resources?

I found an equation $f = \frac{20.1 \times E}{3930}$, whre $f$ is fat in grams and $E$ is energy in mlO2/g ([Hayman et al. 2016. Sci. Adv.](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/1/e1500831)). But the paper is without any explanation as to what the numbers mean, and why they are used. Does anyone know, how to convert oxygen consumption to volume of burnt fat?